# Increase mysql query with sub-query performance

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance, join

hi I have query like this, if I execute it takes about 15 sec, how can I optimize the query?

```
SELECT
    tr.id_igd,
    tr.rm,
    mpa.nama as nm_pasien,
    mpa.no_tlp_pasien as telp_pasien,
    mpa.rating,
    (SELECT d.nama FROM m_pegawai d WHERE d.nip = dokter) AS dokter,
    tr.status_pasien,
    tr.kunjungan,
    tr.tgl_checkup,
    tr.tgl_keluar
FROM
    t_igd tr 
INNER JOIN m_pasien mpa ON mpa.no_rm = tr.rm
```

Comment: Check the explain plan and see if there are places where it could use indexes. Add indexes. Most notably those `no_rm` and `rm` columns might benefit from an index, since they are used in the join, so the database needs them for fast lookups. But since you don't do any filtering (no where clause), there might not be that much to optimize after that. If both tables contain a LOT of data and most of the `rm` values are shared between them, then maybe you're out of luck.

Comment: Please post a schema and EXPLAIN.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `SHOW TABLE STATUS` for each of the three tables.

Answer (score 0):

I mean the subquery can be changed to one more JOIN:

```
SELECT
    tr.id_igd,
    tr.rm,
    mpa.nama as nm_pasien,
    mpa.no_tlp_pasien as telp_pasien,
    mpa.rating,
    d.nama AS dokter,
    tr.status_pasien,
    tr.kunjungan,
    tr.tgl_checkup,
    tr.tgl_keluar
FROM
    t_igd tr 
INNER JOIN m_pasien mpa ON mpa.no_rm = tr.rm
LEFT JOIN m_pegawai d ON d.nip = dokter;
```

Comment: You don't know if the join will change the number of records returned. The correlated subquery will not change it, but the join might.

Comment: In case when the joined table is not one-to-one table then the origin query not been work, so I mean table m_pegawai have not more then 1 row for each t_igd record, so number of returned records not changes